# Deprecation warning when importing Processing in pyQGIS 3

Tags: qgis-processing, pyqgis-3, python-3, qgis-3, importerror

I use QGIS 3.4 with Python 3.7 and I have a warning message when importing Processing like this :

```
import processing
from processing.core.Processing import Processing
```

Here is the message :

```
Using or importing the ABCs from 'collections' instead of from 'collections.abc' is deprecated, and in 3.8 it will stop working
```

What is the new way to import it without getting this DeprecationWarning ?

Comment: there is no new way! That is a message from the library collections that is used by processing! Note: I can not reproduce it

Answer (score 1):

It's a common issue in Python collections library. Many libraries have this warning and should be updated to work with Python 3.8.

Don't worry, QGIS "processing" library should be updated before using Python 3.8. Ignore it for now.